# NO ajax request is happening in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am trying to get sub nodes (in my case sub categories) on clicking in the parent nodes (categories). But I can see no ajax request is happening in my case. I have used the solution from this website - (http://www.miketyka.com/2012/10/lazy-loading-with-jstree-and-ajax/). Here is my jstree code below -

```
/**
  * menu tree generation
  */
 $("#menu_tree")
.bind("open_node.jstree", function (e, data) { // this binding will collapse all nodes whenever user expands any single node
    data.rslt.obj.siblings().filter(".jstree-open").each(function () {
    data.inst.close_node(this);
    });
 })
 .jstree({
    "json_data": {
        "ajax": {
            "url": base_url + "draw/get_child"
        }
     },
     "types": { // this will let user to expand or collapse node by clicking on the node title
       "types": {
         "default": {
            "select_node": function (e) {
                this.toggle_node(e);
                return false;
            }
         }
       }
     },
    "core": {
    "html_titles": true,
    "load_open": true
 },
   "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "html_data", "types", "ui"],
   "themes": {
   "theme": "apple",
   "dots": true,
   "icons": true
  }
});
```

the html part is below -

```
<div class="" id="menu_tree" style="width: 500px;z-index: 1; float: right;position: relative;">
    <ul class="" style="position: absolute;top: 0px;left: 0px;">
    <?php
      if (!empty($parent_categories)) {
          foreach ($parent_categories as $parent_categories) {
    ?>
        <li id="cat<?php echo $parent_categories->objcat_id; ?>">
            <a href="#" class=""><?php echo $parent_categories->category_name; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php
          }
      }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the data i am trying to get is below - (i'm using codeigniter)

```
$this->load->model('object_category_model');
$result = array();
$sub_category = $this->object_category_model->get_subcategories_by_category_id($this->input->post('parent_id'));
echo json_encode($sub_category);
```

I am only loading parent nodes for the first time, all child nodes should load by user click on the parent nodes.

if i use "html_data" rather than "json_data" then a request occurs and i can see a loading gif but then i get this error "Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8", but if i use "json_data" then nothing just happens, no ajax request in the firebug.

i can't understand what's wrong i am doing... Any solution please?

Comment: What can you see int firebug? Is AJAX request sent? Does the web server receive it? Simplify your code. Use only url in ajax to start with. Not sure what "load_open" does. Never used it before.

Comment: @Radek --- no ajax request is sent, that is the problem, for that i can't even understand where to find the error...

Comment: @Radek --- i am trying to load sub nodes by clicking on the parent node name dynamically with ajax.

Comment: Simplify your code. Use only url without any function to start with. Then start adding more and more of your code. No 'type', no "success" property, only plain 'url'.

Comment: @Radek -- i have done what you have told, but still nothing... no ajax request in firebug. please check my edited question description codes

Comment: @Radek -- i have created test code in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rafi_ccj/yndc9/1/)

Comment: You have to read how to make ajax call on jsfiddle. It's not real call but only fake. BTW does base_url got any value in your script?

Comment: @Radek yes, it holds value...

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't display jsTree.

Comment: in my original code too

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/rafi_ccj/yndc9/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27931/discussion-between-rafi-ccj-and-radek)

Comment: sorry I have to go ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 4 days of trying, I have found the problem, wrong I was doing. I was just returning data from php part with wrong format. Now I have fixed the format and it is running well, also I forgot to use "jstree-closed" class. The correct format (format I am now using) is given below-

```
      $sub_category = $this->object_category_model->get_subcategories_by_category_id($_GET['id']);

      if ($sub_category != FALSE) {
           foreach ($sub_category as $sub_category) {

                $result = '<li class="jstree-closed cat" id="' . $sub_category->objcat_id . '"><a href="#">' . $sub_category->category_name . '</a></li>';

                echo $result;
           }
      }
```

And I have used html_data rather than json_data.

```
"html_data" : { //generating child nodes of selected parent node dynamically using ajax
                "ajax" : {
                     "url" : base_url + "draw/get_child",
                     "data" : function (n) {
                          return {
                               id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0
                          };
                     }
                }
           }
```

Thanks everyone for trying to help me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

"json_data" : {
       "ajax" : {
            "url" : function (node) {

to

"json_data" : {
       "ajax" : {
            **cache:false,**
            "url" : function (node) {

Comment: try putting together a demo at jsfiddle.net - that way people can better help you.

Comment: it is very hard to do.... can you tell me what kind of data should i return from the request uri and what should i display for the first time?